# Looking for a micro slide switch On/Off guard that will work on a vintage RC transmitter

Tags: switches, remote-control

I have a very old New in the Box RC transmitter but some of the plastic items are a bit brittle.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: make a replacement from aluminum U-channel or square aluminum tube

Comment: You should use calipers to get those measurements. They will be much more accurate than tape measure.

Answer (score 0):

The damage is done to both ends from excess torque on the flat screw.

It needed a stress relief soft washer like a thin layer of silicon or nylon around the shoulder to isolate the brittle plastic from uneven forces.

My fave solution for this is a drop of polyurethane subfloor adhesive on the mating surfaces applied with a toothpick for tiny parts. It takes  days to air dry unlike the former high VOC stuff that was great plastic.

Looks like the 1st plastic "Bakelite" a very brittle product.